# Flurry age and gender Android

Tags: android, flurry-analytics

Hi I am using flurry analytics in my app. I need to find out the age and gender of the person using the app. how can i do this. Although there is an option to set age and gender but from where i can get that as there is no information in my app about the person's age and gender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of R&D i found that it is not possible to set age and gender without getting it manually from the user through your app. However the flurry itself estimates the age and gender of the user after collecting information of the user but after a suitable period of use.